# Should we place macros in CUDA outside or inside of the __global__ function?

Tags: cuda

My CUDA kernel looks like this.

```
#define MY_AWESOME_MACRO(foo, bar) (foo * bar * 123 + 456)
__global__ void my_CUDA_kernel(int* cool, float* beans) {
    // Some computation.
}
```

Should I place my macro inside or outside of the function? I Googled around, and some did both. Is there harm in doing it one way or the other?

Comment: either way will work, as long as the macro is defined before it gets referenced or expanded somewhere in your code.  The preprocessor handles macros, and so there hasn't really been any code processing done (whether by nvcc or by whatever c compiler you are using) when the macro gets defined and expanded.

Comment: It is more convenient to define the macros at the top of source files or in header files. Makes code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, There is no difference. You can define macros anywhere in the file.

When I used Compute Visual Profiler, the code with Macros defined outside ran faster than the other. I suggest you to use profiler for both of them and check which is suitable for your requirements.